# Avoiding overlaid scatter plots of multiple clusters with different color using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following scatter plot and I want to decrease the transparency of each color to see all the clusters clearly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 1600
np.random.seed(0)
data1 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([2, 0])
data2 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([-2, 0])
data3 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([0, 2])
data4 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([0, -2])
data = np.concatenate((data1, data2, data3, data4))
labels = np.concatenate((n*[1], n*[2], n*[3], n*[4]))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors_list = ['k', 'r', 'orange', 'g']
color_codes = np.asarray(colors_list)
colors = color_codes[labels-1]
ax.scatter(*data.T, c = colors);
```

[image]

**Question**

How can I do it without **For** loop in an efficient way?

**Edit**

```
n = 1600
np.random.seed(0)
data1 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([1, 0])
data2 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([-1, 0])
data3 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([0, 1])
data4 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([0, -1])
data = np.concatenate((data1, data2, data3, data4))
labels = np.concatenate((n*[1], n*[2], n*[3], n*[4]))
# alphas = np.concatenate((n*[.1], n*[.2], n*[.3], n*[.4]))
alphas = np.linspace(0.1, 1, n)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors_list = ['k', 'r', 'orange', 'g']
color_codes = np.asarray(colors_list)
colors = color_codes[labels-1]
ax.scatter(*data.T, c = colors, alpha = 0.1, s=10);

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors_list = ['k', 'r', 'orange', 'g']
color_codes = np.asarray(colors_list)
colors = color_codes[labels-1]

ax.scatter(*data.T, c = colors);
```

[image]

**Problem**

The black cluster is totally overlaid and I cannot see it in the second picture. Is there a way that I can use and find a clear picture that helps me to see all the colors?

Comment: `ax.scatter(*data.T, c=colors, alpha=0.1)`?

Comment: @JohanC: that solves my problem partially, what if want to have different alphas for different cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the same transparency to all, you can use `ax.scatter(*data.T, c=colors, alpha=0.1)`.

To have individual transparencies, you could work with `to_rgba` to include transparency into the colors.

Matplotlib will draw the dots in the order they appear in the array. In the given example, all black dots will be drawn first, all green last. Applying a randomized order could tackle that effect.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba

n = 1600
np.random.seed(0)
data1 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([2, 0])
data2 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([-2, 0])
data3 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([0, 2])
data4 = np.random.randn(n, 2) + np.asarray([0, -2])
data = np.concatenate((data1, data2, data3, data4))
labels = np.concatenate((n * [1], n * [2], n * [3], n * [4]))
labels = np.repeat([1, 2, 3, 4], n)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))
colors_list = [to_rgba('k', 0.05), to_rgba('r', 0.1), to_rgba('orange', 0.15), to_rgba('g', 0.15)]
color_codes = np.asarray(colors_list)
colors = color_codes[labels - 1]

ax1.scatter(*data.T, c=colors)
ax1.set_title('Original order')

order = np.arange(len(labels))
np.random.shuffle(order)
ax2.scatter(*data[order, :].T, c=colors[order])
ax2.set_title('Randomized order')

plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot with individual alpha]

PS: In an alternative, unfortunately deleted, answer, @t.o. showed that in the latest matplotlib versions, `alpha` is now also allowed to be an array.

Comment: Can you post your image? If you so, you can see that the black cluster is totally overlaid. What is you suggestion for that?

Comment: The dots are plotted in the order they appear. You could randomize their order to mix things. I updated the answer to also show that approach.